# Flutter Pagination with request to next page with php laravel

Tags: flutter

I need to implement Pagination in flutter as list of products is very high. I need to make paginate with 20 items show at once. I tried below plugin, but that solution is not working. I have pasted my code without pagination which works fine with only issue when product list is high, it slows down page load time.
is there any other other solution for pagination in flutter. I am using Laravel as backend.

plugin used : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paginator
api: https://androidapp.factory2homes.com/api/get-products-for-mobile-case/26

```
class ProductByPhoneModel extends StatefulWidget {
  final phoneModel;
  ProductByPhoneModel(this.phoneModel);

  List<String> prod = new List();

  @override
  _ProductByPhoneModelState createState() => _ProductByPhoneModelState();
}

class _ProductByPhoneModelState extends State<ProductByPhoneModel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('f2h'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
        future: getProductByPhoneModel(http.Client(), this.widget.phoneModel),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ProductByPhoneModelGrid(
                  product: snapshot.data,
                )
              : Center(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      Container(
                        height: 15,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      Text('Factory2Homes'),
                    ],
                  )),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductByPhoneModelGrid extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Product> product;
  ProductByPhoneModelGrid({this.product});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,

        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
        ),
        itemCount: product.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return InkWell(
         //   onTap: () async {
         //     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/ProductDetailLandingPage',arguments: product[index]);
         //     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         //     createProductPageVisit(prefs.getInt('userId'), 'ProductByCategory', product[index].productId, prefs.getString('token'));
         //   },
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      child: Image.network(
                        product[index].productPhoto,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(product[index].productName, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 3,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(

                                  text:
                                  '\u20B9 ${product[index].productSalePrice}'),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                  ' ${product[index].productListPrice}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                      color: Colors.grey)),
                            ])),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(((1 -
                        product[index].productSalePrice /
                            product[index]
                                .productListPrice) *
                        100)
                        .toStringAsFixed(0) +
                        '% Off', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not used that package, but if you just want to solve this problem you can look at this simple code   [github](https://github.com/zaidzebari/flutter-pagination-laravel), you can make your own without using any package.

**this is code**

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'dart:async';
> import 'dart:convert';
> import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
> import 'package:scroll/server.dart';
>
> class FutureStream extends StatefulWidget {
>   FutureStream({Key key}) : super(key: key);
>   final String name = 'zaid salah';
>   @override
>   _FutureStreamState createState() => _FutureStreamState();
> }
>
> class _FutureStreamState extends State<FutureStream> {
>   var uri = '${Server.domain}/web/vuecrud/public/test';
>   var nexturl;
>   ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
>   List<Test> tempList = [];
>   //determine if all data has been recieved
>   var loadCompleted = false;
>
>   Future<List<Test>> getData(uri) async {
>     final response = await http.get(uri);
>     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
>       var testJson = json.decode(response.body);
>       var data = testJson['data'];
>       if (testJson['next_page_url'] != null) {
>         nexturl = testJson['next_page_url'];
>       } else {
>         loadCompleted = true;
>       }
>       for (var item in data) {
>         Test test =
>             new Test(item["id"], item["name"], item["email"], item["password"]);
>         tempList.add(test);
>       }
>       return tempList;
>     } else {
>       throw Exception('Failed to load Test');
>     }
>   }
>
>   Future<List<Test>> data;
>   @override
>   void initState() {
>     data = getData(uri);
>     scrollindecator();
>     super.initState();
>   }
>
>   void scrollindecator() {
>     _scrollController.addListener(
>       () {
>         if (_scrollController.offset >=
>                 _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
>             !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
>           print('reach to bottom botton');
>           if (!loadCompleted) {
>             setState(() {
>               //add more data to list
>               data = getData(nexturl);
>             });
>           }
>         }
>       },
>     );
>   }
>
>   @override
>   void dispose() {
>     _scrollController.dispose();
>     super.dispose();
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     print("app called again");
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         actions: <Widget>[
>           IconButton(
>             icon: Icon(Icons.search),
>             onPressed: () {},
>           ),
>         ],
>         centerTitle: true,
>         title: Text("stream vs future"),
>       ),
>       body: SingleChildScrollView(
>         controller: _scrollController,
>         child: Column(
>           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
>           children: <Widget>[
>             FutureBuilder(
>               future: data,
>               builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
>                 if (!snapshot.hasData) {
>                   return Container(
>                     child: Center(
>                       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
>                     ),
>                   );
>                 } else {
>                   //if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
>                   return ListView.builder(
>                       physics: ScrollPhysics(),
>                       shrinkWrap: true,
>                       itemCount: snapshot.data.length ?? 0,
>                       itemBuilder: (BuildContext contex, int index) {
>                         if (index == snapshot.data.length - 1 &&
>                             !loadCompleted) {
>                           return Center(
>                             child: new Opacity(
>                               opacity: 1.0,
>                               child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
>                             ),
>                           );
>                         } else {
>                           return ListTile(
>                             leading: CircleAvatar(
>                                 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
>                                 child:
>                                     Text(snapshot.data[index].id.toString())),
>                             title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
>                             subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
>                             trailing: Icon(
>                               Icons.info,
>                               color: Colors.blue,
>                             ),
>                             onTap: () {
>                               print(index);
>                             },
>                           );
>                         }
>                       }
>                       //  },
>                       );
>                 }
>               },
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> class Test {
>   final int id;
>   final String name;
>   final String email;
>   final String password;
>   Test(this.id, this.name, this.email, this.password);
> }
> ```